# How do I make an object travel only in a given space?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem regarding VB.net programming, specifically in moving objects upon keydown event.

So here's the situation. I placed a picturebox inside a panel and made that picturebox move certain distances upon keydown. The problem is that the picturebox seems to overlap(go through walls) the panel.
I'm thinking that the width of the panel has to do with the code to restrict the object from passing through the panel. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find out what method or such should I do to make it happen.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub EClassic_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Left
            play_avatar.Left -= 100
            If play_avatar.Left = -200 Then
                Keys.Left. = Nothing
            End If
        Case Keys.Right
            play_avatar.Left += 100
            If play_avatar.Left = 200 Then
                Keys.Left. = Nothing
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Your response is very much appreciated! Thank you.

EDIT:

I think this worked fine, thanks @Lolo. Although my coding looks very cheap lol.

```
Dim c As Integer = Panel1.ClientSize.Width
    Dim res As Integer
    Dim res2 As Integer
    res2 = c - c + 100
    res = c / 2

    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Left
            If play_avatar.Left > res2 Then
                play_avatar.Left -= 100
            ElseIf play_avatar.Left < res2 Then
                play_avatar.Left -= 0
            End If

        Case Keys.Right
            If play_avatar.Left < res Then
                play_avatar.Left += 100
            ElseIf play_avatar.Left > res Then
                play_avatar.Left -= 0

            End If

    End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub EClassic_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
  Dim tmpLeft as integer

  Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.Left
      tmpLeft =play_avatar.Left - 100

      If tmpLeft < YourPanel.Left then
       e.cancel=true
      else
        play_avatar.Left = tmpLeft 
      End If

    Case Keys.Right
      tmpLeft =play_avatar.Left + 100

      If play_avatar.Right > YourPanel.Right then
        e.cancel=true
      else
         play_avatar.Left = tmpLeft 
      End If

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work for me.  
I may want to know if this is possible?

`Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Left
                play_avatar.Left -= 100
                If play_avatar.Left = -200 Then
                    'Is there any way to disable a key if this condition is met?
                End If
            Case Keys.Right
                play_avatar.Left += 100
                If play_avatar.Left = 200 Then
                    'Is there any way to disable a key if this condition is met?
                End If
        End Select`

Comment: do not assign a value to (play_avatar.Left) until your condition is satisfied. Use a variable to first test the new value after adding/subtracting 100 then assign this value to (play_avatar.Left). You can not disable the keyboard handling event you only can cancel the event if your condition is not satisfied. Use (e.Cancel = True) instead of ( Keys.Left. = Nothing).

Comment: @Lolo: You've got a dot after the `Keys.Left.` - it should be simply `Keys.Left`. I still suspect the logic is slightly flawed here, as you're comparing a movement to the left with the right hand edge of the panel and vice versa...